# Celery stale issue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am having below issue and it keeps on continuing. It starts with missed heartbeats and whenever I try to give a task then this issue will keep on going.

```
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 16:09:27.226 [warning] <0.566.0> closing AMQP connection <0.566.0> (172.18.0.10:33754 -> 172.18.0.7:5672):
rabbit_1         | missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 16:09:45.486 [warning] <0.583.0> closing AMQP connection <0.583.0> (172.18.0.9:35682 -> 172.18.0.7:5672):
rabbit_1         | missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.258 [info] <0.31892.9> connection <0.31892.9> (172.18.0.10:42580 -> 172.18.0.8:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.260 [warning] <0.31892.9> closing AMQP connection <0.31892.9> (172.18.0.10:42580 -> 172.18.0.8:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
rabbit_1         | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.266 [info] <0.31907.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.31907.9> (172.18.0.10:42582 -> 172.18.0.8:5672)
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.267 [info] <0.31907.9> connection <0.31907.9> (172.18.0.10:42582 -> 172.18.0.8:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.269 [warning] <0.31907.9> closing AMQP connection <0.31907.9> (172.18.0.10:42582 -> 172.18.0.8:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
rabbit_1         | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.284 [info] <0.31922.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.31922.9> (172.18.0.10:42584 -> 172.18.0.8:5672)
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.286 [info] <0.31922.9> connection <0.31922.9> (172.18.0.10:42584 -> 172.18.0.8:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
rabbit_1         | 2018-07-23 12:47:05.292 [warning] <0.31922.9> closing AMQP connection <0.31922.9> (172.18.0.10:42584 -> 172.18.0.8:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
```

Comment: Is your rabbitmq behind a load balancer?

Comment: I guess rabbitmq is not behind